# What does loadChildren mean and what to use in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I have the following questions:

1. I moved to Ionic 4 and I can see that instead of `{ path: '', component: WalkthroughComponent }` it's written `{ path: '', loadChildren: '/Walktrhough#WalkthroughModule'}`. May I know the difference in details? My app is not so big there will be 25-30 routes at all, and I don't want to use loadChildren at all. What do you think?
2. Ionic 4 has pages thing, which means you can create pages. I learned Angular so that I was only creating components. So main home page was also a component. Everything was a component. Is this wrong ? Can I follow this structure in Ionic 4?
3. I am interested in the difference between

   ```
    this.navCtrl.navigateRoot("/error");
   ```

   and

   ```
    this.router.navigateRoot("/error");.
   ```

   When to use which?

Comment: 1) LoadChildren is used for lazy loaded modules. If you have a relatively small app I'd go for your first option.

Comment: can I know the difference ? i don't understand why i'd want to lazy load a single page. when does it make sense?

Comment: Usually, all the components are loaded when the app runs, lazy loading is loading the component whenever needed without loading it initially. This improves the performance of the application.

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks guys. what about the third question?

Comment: Router is used in angular application. Ionic is mostly used for creating mobile apps, it does not support url routes, so they have created another method for navigating through pages. Using navCtrl, one can easily add or remove pages(behaves like a stack)